# exe obfuscated with Dotfuscator does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, dotfuscator

I have developed an application in WPF C#, with MVVM pattern. I've created a setup project with InstallShield to distrubute my application.
Now, to avoid reverse engineering, I am using Dotfuscator embedded in VS2012.
I obfuscate the exe file without changing anything in settings, leaving the defaults. When I run the application, I notice that something does not work...
Otherwise, the exe without any obfuscation works correctly.

here is the gist of the window in which code breaks...https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a170188c026f5e8eca4c
In particular, when I select an item into the TreeView, normal behaviour must be that user see labels and textboxes accordingly to item selected; in this case, nothing is shown...maybe because there is a Converter in the Visibility property of the objects.

Why does this happen? How can I have an obfuscated exe without breaking it?

Is there some settings in Dotfuscator that I need to check?

Comment: Well then fix something. In general, obfuscation does not functionally change your code. So if something breaks, isolate what is broken.

Comment: Exe without obfuscation works correctly. So maybe obfuscation do something that breaks the application...

Comment: I guess obfuscation could break something if you used reflection with hard coded names?

Comment: Yeah sure, but what do you want us to do? Guess what is broken? Include all relevant details in your question.

Comment: Regarding your edit, no, there is not "some setting" called "PleaseDontBreakMyCode". You need to **isolate what code breaks** and **include this in your question**.

Comment: Did you make sure that all the dlls and files your not obfuscated exe needed are in the same folder as the obfuscated exe?